# Is there a good term for pairs of related variables in a system?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, linear-programming

(Non-mathematician here.  Sorry).

Suppose you have a problem with lots of unknowns.  The problem allows many solutions (possibly infinite).

Certain pairs of unknowns (you don't know which ones) are related in such a way that they add up to a given integer in all solutions.  For example, 
$$x_1+x_2=C$$

where $C$ has the same value in all solutions.

Is there a term of art for such a pair as $(x_1,x_2)$ that describes the fact that if one goes up, the other must go down by the same amount?

I was thinking along the lines of "conjugate pairs", which I know isn't right.

Comment: Ther proper term is *complementary* pairs. For pairs with a given difference, you could use *anticomplementary*.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've never heard a special term for that. The term *conjugate pair* is used for a bunch of different things, so you may want to pick another term to avoid overloading that one even more. May I suggest *balancing pair*?

Comment: Thanks, Yves!  I like that.